# changed windows and now the same android studio project wont run

Tags: android, android-emulator

i reinstalled windows transferred the project by making zip file of it
now it builds the apk but apk doesnot install and shows error "App not installed"

i have changed the sha 1 fingerprint and the apk installs in emultor but doesnot install on physical device

there maybe only a minor mistake that i am missing

i would but i need to add an important detail i tried creating the basic map activity with no coding in it other that what android studio provides it also doesn't install on phone so there is something wrong with android studio

here is manifest if it helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.hpuser.map">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:testOnly="false">
        <activity
            android:name=".BussesList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_busses_list"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".HistoryMap" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_history_list"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB93vemwD047fcDdFbk0iHMs8WYQZGXVdc" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginPage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

following are the errors in logcat

```
04-02 21:22:33.723 19343-19343/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
04-02 21:22:33.723 19343-19343/? E/Zygote: v2
04-02 21:22:33.733 19343-19343/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
```

Comment: Can you post the complete logcat error ?

Comment: i would but i need to add an important detail i tried creating the basic map activity with no codeing in it other that what android studio provides it also doesnot install on phone so threre is something wrong with android studio

Comment: have you tried invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: I need to make sure you have your jdk installed after reinstalling windows

Comment: yes i have jdk installed and i ahve tried invalidate cache and restart